# Matplotlib - 2 problems. Common colorbar / labels not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I finally forced the 3 plots I want into one plot with 3 subplots...now I need to add a common colorbar, preferably horizontally oriented. Also, now that I have them as subplots, I have lost the labels that were there in a previous iteration.

It seems that the examples suggest I [add an axes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multi_image.html), but I don't quite get what the numbers in the arguments are.

```
def plot_that_2(x_vals, y_vals, z_1_vals, z_2_vals, z_3_vals, figname, units, efficiency_or_not):
    global letter_pic_width    
    plt.close()    #I moved this up from the end of the file because it solved my QTagg problem
    UI = [uniformity_calc(z_1_vals), uniformity_calc(z_2_vals), uniformity_calc(z_3_vals)]
    ranges = [ str(int(np.max(z_1_vals) - np.min(z_1_vals))), str(int(np.max(z_2_vals) - np.min(z_2_vals))), str(int(np.max(z_3_vals) - np.min(z_3_vals)))]
    z_vals = [z_1_vals, z_2_vals, z_3_vals]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (letter_pic_width, letter_pic_width/3 ))
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1, aspect = 1)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2, aspect = 1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3, aspect = 1)

    axenames = [ax0, ax1, ax2]

    for z_val, unif, rangenum, ax in zip(z_vals, UI, ranges, axenames):
        ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, c = z_val, s = 100, cmap = 'rainbow')
        if efficiency_or_not:
            ax.vmin = 0
            ax.vmax = 1
            ax.xlabel = 'Uniformity: ' + unif
        else:
            ax.xlabel = 'Uniformity: ' + unif + '   ' + rangenum + ' ppm'

    plt.savefig('./'+ figname + '.jpg', dpi = 100)
```

[image: This is the plot when efficiency = True. I think it's not setting the vmin / vmax, either.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the xlabel, use `ax.set_xlabel('Uniformity: ' + unif)` See more information [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) in the documentation for axes.

The example you linked to uses the `add_axes` method of a figure as an alternative to `add_subplot`. The [documentation for figures](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html) explains what the numbers in add_axes are: "Add an axes at position rect [left, bottom, width, height] where all quantities are in fractions of figure width and height."

```
rect = l,b,w,h
fig.add_axes(rect)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the explanation! For some reason, it is now reversing the colorbar, and I am confused about that, but "visible" and "exists" are both good qualities to have in a colorbar!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the colorbar axis, the numbers represent

```
[bottom_left_x_coord, bottom_left_y_coord, width, height]
```

An appropriate colorbar might be

```
# x    y    w     h
[0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.05]
```

Here's your code, somewhat reworked which adds a colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WIDTH = 9

def uniformity_calc(x):
    return x.mean()

def plotter(x, y, zs, name, units, efficiency=True):
    fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(WIDTH, WIDTH/3), 
                              subplot_kw={'aspect':1})
    fig.suptitle(name)

    UI = map(uniformity_calc, zs)
    ranges = map(lambda x: int(np.max(x)-np.min(x)), zs)

    for ax, z, unif, rangenum in zip(axarr, zs, UI, ranges):
        scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, cmap='rainbow')
        label = 'Uniformity: %i'%unif
        if not efficiency:
            label += '    %i ppm'%rangenum
        ax.set_xlabel(label)

    # Colorbar [left, bottom, width, height
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.05])
    cbar = fig.colorbar(scat, cax, orientation='horizontal')
    cbar.set_label('This is a colorbar')
    plt.show()


def main():
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
    zs = [np.random.rand(*y.shape) for _ in range(3)]
    plotter(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), zs, 'name', None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]