# matplotlib fig size with colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce two figure. The second one is equal to the first one, with the only exception that it has superimposed an image with the corresponding colorbar. I need this in a presentation for a correct overlay. The code I'm using is the following

```
import matplotlib as mpl
# first figure 
fig = mpl.pylab.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel(r'x')
ax.set_ylabel(r'y')
ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylim([0,1])
mpl.pylab.savefig('one.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')

# second figure
fig = mpl.pylab.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel(r'x')
ax.set_ylabel(r'y')
ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylim([0,1])
im = ax.imshow(image,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=(0,1,0.5,1))
cb = fig.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical')
cb.set_label(r'p$_e$ [Pa]', fontsize = 18)
mpl.pylab.savefig('two.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

The problem is that I would like that the canvas (I think this is the correct name, i.e. the space occupied by the axis and label) to be exactly the same for the two figures, whereas the second one is shrink because of the colorbar. How can I correctly determine the size for the figures?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091585/matplotlib-2-problems-common-colorbar-labels-not-showing-up)

You can also check out [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_edge_colorbar.html)

I would recommend either plotting both plots on the same figure, making a grid, or doing a separate colorbar as in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
# first plot 
plt.subplot(131)
...
# second plot
plt.subplot(132)
...

#colorbar
plt.subplot(133)
...
```

Comment: For the keynote I'm preparing I need separate figure for dynamically showing the different things. I cannot arrange it in a single plot with subfigure. So this is not a solution. What I can try is to move the colorbar on the top although I don't like it

Comment: If I were you, then, I would have the colorbar in a third figure.